# Hide the HTML5 game for specific devices in KiK

Tags: kik

Is there any ability to hide the HTML5 game in KiK on certain devices/OSes?
"to hide" means not to show the game in KiK search results.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Think of it as any other search engine where it'll just go out and find what's available and categorically offer that up to users.